# How to run a github workflow job conditionally and pass env vars between jobs

Tags: bash, github, devops, github-actions, cicd

I have this in my github workflow .yml file

```yaml
name: Release workflow (pipeline)

# Enable Buildkit and let compose use it to speed up image building
env:
  DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
  COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD: 1
  RELEASE_ID: ''  # this env var will be modified in Create release job > Set release number step, so to be used in the deploy job

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: Environment to create the release for
        required: true
        type: choice
        options:
          # - dev
          - prod
        default: prod

      should_auto_deploy:
        description: Auto-deploy the release
        required: false
        type: boolean
        default: 'false'

# some other lines

jobs:
  create_release:
    name: Create release
    needs: run_tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # i have this line in the bash script for this step, to modify the global env var above
      # echo "RELEASE_ID=$releaseId" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Set release number
        run: |
          chmod +x ./scripts/github-workflow/set-release-number.sh
          ./scripts/github-workflow/set-release-number.sh \
            -e ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }} \
            -n $(date +%Y-%m-%d)-${{ github.ref_name }}-${{ github.run_id }}

# some other lines

  deploy:
    name: Deploy release
    needs: create_release
    # this is the problematic condition.
    # this job ALWAYS runs even when i dont tick the checkbox to set `github.event.inputs.should_auto_deploy` to true
    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.should_auto_deploy && needs.create_release.result == 'success' }}
    uses: Aplanke/ApiBackend/.github/workflows/deployment.yml@main
    with:
      environment: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}
      # the updated env var should be passed to this job
      release_number: ${{ github.env.RELEASE_ID }}
```

What I expect:

1. Asked in [How to pass data between github workflow jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079319/how-to-pass-data-between-github-workflow-jobs)
2. The deploy job should only run when `github.event.inputs.should_auto_deploy` is true and the `create_release` job was successful

What happens:
The `deploy` jub always runs, even when `github.event.inputs.should_auto_deploy` is false (not selected in UI)

How do I fix these?

Comment: You can declare an output variable in the `create_release` job and evaluate it in the `deploy` - Check the docs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs

Comment: Still does not work. I changed to this..

```yml
create_release:
    name: Create release
    outputs:
      release_number: ${{ steps.set_release_number.outputs.release_number }}
    steps:
      - name: Set release number
        id: set_release_number
       # this step runs the below command
       # echo "::set-output name=release_number::$releaseId"

deploy:
    name: Deploy release
    needs: create_release
    uses: Aplanke/ApiBackend/.github/workflows/deployment.yml@main
    with:
      release_number: ${{ needs.create_release.outputs.release_number }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booleans in GitHub actions are not real booleans, you can read about the problem [here](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1483).

You have to use:
`{{ github.event.inputs.should_auto_deploy == 'true' }}`

And for ENV variable - it's really bad approach to use ENV variables like that - there is explicit way of exchanging data between jobs described in [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs)

At the end this workflow should be like this:

```
jobs:
  create_release:
    name: Create release
    needs: run_tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs: ${{ steps.set_release_number.release_id }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set release number
        id: set_release_number
        run: echo "::set-output name=release_id::RELEASE_ID"
  deploy:
    name: Deploy release
    needs: create_release
    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.should_auto_deploy == 'true' && needs.create_release.result == 'success' }}
    uses: Aplanke/ApiBackend/.github/workflows/deployment.yml@main
    with:
      environment: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}
      release_number: ${{ needs.create_release.outputs.release_id }}
```

Comment: Why does `create_release: outputs: release_number: ${{ steps.set_release_number.release_number }}` 
`deploy: with: release_number: ${{ needs.create_release.outputs.release_number }}`
not work?

Comment: It should - are you sure the value is properly set for you `release_number` ?

Comment: Yes but it still doesn't pass the value. Her's what i have now

```
create_release:
    outputs:
      release_id: ${{ steps.set_release_number.outputs.release_number }}
    step:
      - id: set_release_number
        run: |
RELEASE_NUMBER=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)-main-1823909529
echo "::set-output name=release_number::$RELEASE_NUMBER"

deploy:
    needs: create_release
    if: (needs.create_release.result == 'success') && (github.event.inputs.should_auto_deploy == 'true')
    uses: ...
```

Comment: That's unreadable, please another question maybe where code formatting will be applied

Comment: Done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079319/how-to-pass-data-between-github-workflow-jobs. 
Thanks, I was able to fix the condition aspect