# How to pass data between github workflow jobs

Tags: github, devops, github-actions, cicd

How do I pass the release number in the `create_release` job to the `deploy` job?

```yaml
...
jobs:
  create_release:
    name: Create release
    needs: run_tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      release_id: ${{ steps.set_release_number.outputs.release_number }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set release number
        id: set_release_number
        run: |
          RELEASE_NUMBER=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)-${{ github.ref_name }}-${{ github.run_id }}
          chmod +x ./scripts/github-workflow/set-release-number.sh
          ./scripts/github-workflow/set-release-number.sh \
            -e ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }} \
            -n $RELEASE_NUMBER
          echo "::set-output name=release_number::$RELEASE_NUMBER"
      - name: Build and upload release
        env:
          DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}
          DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          chmod +x ./scripts/github-workflow/build-and-publish-release.sh
          ./scripts/github-workflow/build-and-publish-release.sh
  deploy:
    name: Deploy release
    needs: create_release
    if: (needs.create_release.result == 'success') && (github.event.inputs.should_auto_deploy == 'true')
    uses: Aplanke/ApiBackend/.github/workflows/deployment.yml@main
    with:
      environment: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}
      release_number: ${{ needs.create_release.outputs.release_id }}
```

**EDIT: Add deploy pipeline snippet**

```yaml
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: Environment to deploy to
        required: true
        type: string
        default: prod
      release_number:
        description: Release number/ID to deploy
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  deployment:
    steps:
      - name: Set release number
        run: |
          chmod +x ./scripts/github-workflow/set-release-number.sh
          ./scripts/github-workflow/set-release-number.sh \
            -e ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }} \
            -n ${{ github.event.inputs.release_number }}
```

Screenshot of the failed job
[image: Screenshot of the failed job]

Comment: What you're showing should work, per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs. Presumably it doesn't - can you give a [mre] showing what happens?

Comment: I have seen the upload/download actions but this is just a string I need to pass to another job. An artifact looks overkill

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted it's working fine:

https://github.com/grzegorzkrukowski/stackoverflow_tests/runs/5155488550?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:4

The problem must be somewhere in how you generate RELEASE_NUMBER or how you handle input in your customs scripts we don't see.
The GitHub Workflow part is working just fine.

Comment: Right. i see it should work. maybe i'm missing something. I've added the deployment snippet to the question

Comment: Well it seems you already don't  have it on `github.event.inputs.release_number`

Comment: I finally figured it out. The problem was in the called workflow. I had to use `inputs.release_number` instead of `github.event.inputs.release_number`. It's kinda annoying why github actions has these nuances

Comment: It's well described for composite actions. Glad it helped.